# Why should I use the function migration in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

What is wrong with using database tables with phpmyadmin or mysql? What are the benefits, if I'll use 'migration'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't use CodeIgniter, but as a Rails developer who used to just use phpMyAdmin and now uses migrations I'd say the primary benefits are:

1. It's an easy way to port the code to a different workstation. Instead of having to dump the SQL file and import it into the other workstation, you just run the migrations.
2. It allows you to keep your database schema in sync with your co-workers. When a table is modified, everyone can just run the migration and you're good to go.
3. It allows you to easily roll back database changes if they cause problems.
4. It documents the changes made to the database structure.